# Recursive TCL proc without explicit return

Tags: recursion, tcl

I am writting a simple "proc" to calculate the factorial. I would like to understand why my function does not work without the return statement.

According to TCL docs, functions that are defined without explicit "return",
return the value of the last executed command in its body.

```
    proc fac { n } {
       if { $n == 1 } {
         return 1
       } 
    puts $n
    set n [expr {$n - 1}]
    return [expr {[fac $n ] * $n}]                                                                                                                                                            
    }
    puts [fac 5] # ans 24
```

When the "return" is removed, I get the following error message:

```
    invalid command name "1"
      while executing
     "[expr {[fac $n ] * $n}] "
        (procedure "fac" line 7)
        invoked from within
```

I expected that without the explicit "return", the function should return 24 as well.

Comment: Why do you think `5! == 24`?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but it can be implemented like this: `proc ::tcl::mathfunc::fac {n} { expr {$n == 1 ? 1 : $n * fac($n - 1)} }` then `expr {fac(6)}`

Comment: Your proc does not return any error on Tcl 8.5 or 8.6... Just that your way of calculating the factorial is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectation is correct. But you have square brackets around `expr` procedure in the last line. It is:

```
[expr {[fac $n] * $n}]
```

This means for the interpreter: 1) execute `expr` procedure with given argument; 2) execute the result of `expr` procedure. Because of this, the interpreter tries to execute procedure `1` that doesn't exist and you receive an error.

To fix this error - just remove square brackets from the last line:

```
proc fac { n } {
   if { $n == 1 } {
     return 1
   } 
   puts $n
   set n [expr {$n - 1}]
   expr {[fac $n ] * $n}                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it is not clear to me why it works with "return".  Why in this case the interpreter doesn't try to execute [1] again?

Comment: The interpreter uses the first word as the name of the command. Return is a command which accepts arguments, one of which can be the value your wish to return as the value of the procedure. In your case, the argument you have given is the return value of executing the expr command. The expr command, its arguments and the enclosing brackets were substituted with the result of execution of the expr command itself.  Absent any explicit return command, procedures return the value of the last executed command. This is why the unadorned expr command works.